# How is spectral rendering handled?

Tags: lighting, photo-realistic, color-science

Is all [spectral rendering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_rendering) handled as simulation?  Are there technique more tailored to 'consumer' rendering, such as for real-time or even just 'realistic looking without solving full physical equations'?

I'd like to understand how we handle the rendering of spectral effects.  It seems like a photon needs to be described as a range of wavelengths, and incidence with a surface either

- replaces the original, and resolves multiple new photons across the spectral function, each with their own new vector
- maintains the original (or marginally modified) photon, given a threshold

I would prefer to be pointed in the direction of existing work, but appreciate any *coloring* of this topic.

Comment: I feel like this question is way too broad as it stands. Whole books have been written on the subject. Perhaps you could narrow it down to a specific question that's not covered by existing resources?

Comment: I can see this being answered along the lines of "There are hundreds of ways, each of which falls into one of the following N broad categories. If you want to know specific detail about one of these categories you can ask a new question."

Answer (score 2):

The most common way I saw is to have photons of several different wavelengths. One then renders with each wavelength and blends the results into the final image.

"Existing work": [Psychopath Renderer](http://psychopath.io/spectral-rendering/) and [The Secret Life of Photons](http://benedikt-bitterli.me/tantalum/).

Answer (score 1):

One hacky method I've seen in real time raytracers / ray marching is to cast a ray per color channel (rgb) and do things Iike have different refraction indices per color channel.

Comment: Interesting. Could you point us to any sources, examples or results of this approach?

Comment: I'm on my phone so can't take a screenshot, but this shadertoy uses the method and looks pretty decent: https://www.shadertoy.com/view/ltfXDM

Comment: POV-Ray is an open-source ray-tracer that uses a similar method to simulate dispersion. It's not a ray per channel: you can configure how many rays are used, spread equally across the spectrum.